# Problems with Xamarin calling localhost API

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile

I believe this problem had been asked before but I am getting really frustrated.

I am developing a Xamarin app and I need it to access an API that will do all transaction accessing a SQL DB.

I have no problem with the Xamarin UI but I can't make it accessing my API. I have been trying a lot of things, suggestions from this place and from others but no luck. If I call my API from Postman it works but no from Xamarin. Honestly I have spent a good time on this, so any light at the end of this tunnel will be very appreciated. I will place the code I am doing below.

This is a simple method to insert a new User on the database:

```
    // POST: Register
    [Route("api/RegisterController/Register")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Register()          
    {
       tblRegister addreg = new tblRegister();
       addreg.Name = "Mr. Blablabla";        
       addreg.Mobile = "12345678";           
       addreg.Email = "asas@jkjk.com";                         
       addreg.Password = "psw";            
       kdbctx.tblRegisters.InsertOnSubmit(addreg);
       kdbctx.SubmitChanges();
       return Ok();
    }
```

and here the Xamarim call:

```
    public bool SendRegistration()
    {
       try
      {
        bool retreg = false;
        var apiurl = "http://localhost:44324/api/RegisterController/Register";
        var regobj = new RegisterModel()
        {
          Name = txtName.Text.Trim(),     //I am not using this values just for the test.
          Mobile = txtMobile.Text.Trim(),  // I am passing in hard code but when it works
          Email = txtEmail.Text.Trim(),      // they will be passed as on object
          Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim()
        };
    
         var regjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(regobj);
         var regcontent = new StringContent(regjson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         var regresponse =  httpClient.PostAsync(apiurl, regcontent);
         if (regresponse.IsFaulted) return false; 
                return true;
      }
      catch(Exception err)
      {
        string erro = err.InnerException.ToString();
         return false;
      }
    }
```

Also the Xamarin does not crash or give me an error but it is not hitting the API.

Comment: Do not use localhost.  Use the IP or FQDN of the server

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for your reply.  At this stage I am working on local machine, not server. I tried before using the machine IP but no luck. I will try again. Thanks

Comment: localhost means local to the Android device/emulator. Not the hosting machine. On Android if you want to access the hosting machine use `10.0.2.2`. As soon as you deploy to a device, you will have to use the IP address or fully qualified domain name (FQDN) again